How to integrate Modal from Laravel Breeze React starter kit?
This was the original code from the Modal Component that came along with the Laravel Breeze React starter kit, but I can't see to get the modal to show up - is this code only for a dark background of low opacity to appear?
import { Fragment } from "react";
import { Dialog, Transition } from "@headlessui/react";
import IconClose from "./IconClose";

export default function Modal({
    children,
    show,
    maxWidth = "2xl",
    closeable = true,
    onClose = () => {},
}) {
    const close = () => {
        if (closeable) {
            onClose();
        }
    };

    const maxWidthClass = {
        sm: "sm:max-w-sm",
        md: "sm:max-w-md",
        lg: "sm:max-w-lg",
        xl: "sm:max-w-xl",
        "2xl": "sm:max-w-2xl",
    }[maxWidth];

    return (
        <Transition show={show} as={Fragment} leave="duration-200">
            <Dialog
                as="div"
                id="modal"
                className="fixed inset-0 flex overflow-y-auto px-4 py-6 sm:px-0 items-center z-50 transform transition-all"
                onClose={close}
            >
                <Transition.Child
                    as={Fragment}
                    enter="ease-out duration-300"
                    enterFrom="opacity-0"
                    enterTo="opacity-100"
                    leave="ease-in duration-200"
                    leaveFrom="opacity-100"
                    leaveTo="opacity-0"
                >
                    <div className="absolute inset-0 bg-gray-500/75 dark:bg-gray-900/75" />
                </Transition.Child>

                <Transition.Child
                    as={Fragment}
                    enter="ease-out duration-300"
                    enterFrom="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
                    enterTo="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
                    leave="ease-in duration-200"
                    leaveFrom="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
                    leaveTo="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
                >
                    <Dialog.Panel
                        className={`mb-6 bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 rounded-lg overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:w-full sm:mx-auto ${maxWidthClass}`}
                    >
                        {children}

                    </Dialog.Panel>
                </Transition.Child>
            </Dialog>
        </Transition>
    );
}

I am not sure where to put the text content of my modal, but I have placed it in a <div> within Dialog.Panel:
           <Dialog.Panel className={`z-0 mb-6 bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 rounded-lg overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:w-full sm:mx-auto ${maxWidthClass}`}
                    >
                        {children}

                        <div className="z-10">
                            Is this where things are supposed to go? Is there no
                            window? Why cant i clsoe this
                            <IconClose onClick={() => close()} />
                        </div>
                    </Dialog.Panel>

but even with the z-index, the div still hides behind the background of lower opacity:
screenshot here
I can't seem to find any tutorial or explanation of how to integrate this in-built Modal Component into my React Application. Can someone offer some advice?

have you tried maybe removing all those code and just try to do a simple modal without params?
